# List sub-directories with ls

Tags: linux, shell

How could I list sub-directories with ls, with '-d' only the current directory is shown. I want something like `find . -type d -maxdepth 1` would give me.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to write: `find . -type d -maxdepth 1` (with no `=` for `-maxdepth`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should help:

`ls -d */`

`*/` will only match directories under the current dir. The output directory names will probably contain the trailing '/' though.

Comment: To be pedantic about this, you should do `ls -d .*/ */` or `shopt -s dotglob; ls -d .*/`, otherwise directories starting with dot (`.`) will not be listed.

Comment: Still confused about the meaning of `*/`

Comment: @ZhaoGang See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directories-using-ls-in-bash-an-examination

Answer (score 7):

You can combine with grep:

```
ls -l | grep '^d'
```

To get just the filenames:

```
ls -l | grep '^d' | awk '{ print $9 }'
```

You can make this into a handy **alias**:

```
alias ldir="ls -l | grep '^d'"
```

Comment: If you are already using `awk`, `grep` is superfluous: `ls -l | awk '/^d/ { print $9 }'`

Answer (score 6):

`ls -d */` and `ls -d */*/` seem to work just fine.