# Listing only directories using ls in Bash?

Tags: bash, directory, ls

This command lists directories in the current path:

```bash
ls -d */
```

What exactly does the pattern `*/` do?

And how can we give the absolute path in the above command (e.g. `ls -d /home/alice/Documents`) for listing only directories in that path?

Comment: It's always funny when the Closed question is the first result from duckduckgo search and answers my question.  

Answer (score 1336, accepted):

`*/` is a pattern that matches all of the subdirectories in the current directory (`*` would match all files *and* subdirectories; the `/` restricts it to directories). Similarly, to list all subdirectories under /home/alice/Documents, use `ls -d /home/alice/Documents/*/`

Comment: Note that `*/` won't match any hidden folders. To include them, either specify them explicitly like `ls -d .*/ */`, or [set the `dotglob` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) in Bash.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The message of failure could be avoided with bash option `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: @BinaryZebra Setting nullglob would avoid the error message, but would cause even more confusion: with nullglob set and no subdirectories, `ls */` would expand to just `ls`, which would list all files in the current directory. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want in that case.

Comment: `*/` also sets the names of the subdirs to be displayed with a trailing slash.

Comment: List all folders exclude `./` `../`: `ls -d */ .[^.]*/`

Comment: [This answer on the Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/576589/where-can-i-find-a-definitive-answer-for-what-means-in-bash-or-zsh/576597#576597) details the POSIX standard for this.

Comment: In this case ls prints filenames differently - in full format. Had to trim it to base name `ls -d /$HOM$/*/ | xargs -L1 basename`

Comment: Improved version: `ls -d .*/ */ 2>/dev/null` where there are not dirs.

Comment: */ is bash globbing.  for  instance echo */ works too.

Answer (score 614):

### Four ways to get this done, each with a different output format

#### 1. Using `echo`

Example: `echo */`, `echo */*/`
Here is what I got:

```
cs/ draft/ files/ hacks/ masters/ static/  
cs/code/ files/images/ static/images/ static/stylesheets/
```

#### 2. Using `ls` only

Example: `ls -d */`
Here is exactly what I got:

```
cs/     files/      masters/  
draft/  hacks/      static/
```

Or as list (with detail info): `ls -dl */`

#### 3. Using `ls` and `grep`

Example: `ls -l | grep "^d"`
Here is what I got:

```
drwxr-xr-x  24 h  staff     816 Jun  8 10:55 cs  
drwxr-xr-x   6 h  staff     204 Jun  8 10:55 draft  
drwxr-xr-x   9 h  staff     306 Jun  8 10:55 files  
drwxr-xr-x   2 h  staff      68 Jun  9 13:19 hacks  
drwxr-xr-x   6 h  staff     204 Jun  8 10:55 masters  
drwxr-xr-x   4 h  staff     136 Jun  8 10:55 static
```

#### 4. Bash Script (Not recommended for filename containing spaces)

Example: `for i in $(ls -d */); do echo ${i%%/}; done`
Here is what I got:

```
cs  
draft  
files  
hacks  
masters  
static
```

If you like to have '/' as ending character, the command will be: `for i in $(ls -d */); do echo ${i}; done`

```
cs/  
draft/  
files/  
hacks/  
masters/  
static/
```

Comment: **NB.** `3` was noticeably slower than the others for me. In the directory I tested: `1` .012s, `2` .016s, `3` **.055s**, `4` .021s.

Comment: @isomorphismes, how did you measure the time? By what means? By the way, I have to say, No. `1` is my favorite.

Comment: Albert, I used `time`, the Unix function. /// I agree, `echo */` is cleverer than `ls -d */`.

Comment: Two minor things that you should note. ls -l | grep "^d" filters out symbolic links to directories, whereas 'ls -d */' displays them.

Also, 'ls -d */' fails if there are no directories present at all in the target directory.

Comment: `ll -d */` worked beautifully for me, thanks for distilling an overabundance of man pages for that insightful tip.

Comment: The `1.` option will cause major pains when dealing with folders names that have spaces.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Will this fix be OK? `printf "%s\n" */ | tr -d "/"`.

Comment: ls -dl */ is a bit simpler than ls -l | grep "^d"

Comment: For me, this command worked wonderfully (thanks for the idea): `for i in $(ls -d */); do printf ${i%%/} && printf " "; done` instead of newlines, it will leave blank spaces between folders (can be modified with other printfs).

Comment: `for i in $(ls -d */); do [...]; done` has 2 issues:
(1) names with blank chars (space, etc...) will be separated entries, and
(2) if a file starts with a `-`, it will be considered as an option.
Better to use globs here: `for i in */; do [...]; done` - probably with prior `shopt -s nullglob`, to avoid the need to check for dirs existence (in case there are no dir).

For problem 2, we could think about `ls -d -- */` or `ls -d ./*`, but still issue 1 will not be handled.
**Ref:** Shellcheck SC2035 & 2045.

Answer (score 137):

I use:

```
ls -d */ | cut -f1 -d'/'
```

This creates a single column without a trailing slash - useful in scripts.

Comment: The `-1` option for `ls` will output in single-column format as well, as in `ls -1 -d */`.

Comment: @user29020 Should note that `-1` still outputs a trailing slash for every entry.

Comment: When I add this to `.bashrc` as alias, how do I add `'/'`?

Comment: @RNA late to answer, but for future people: try escaping with a backslash? `'\/'`

Comment: Breaks if there's a leading slash. This removes trailing slashes only: `| sed -e 's-/$--'`

Comment: @Kalin I used to support the -1, but in reality you don't need it. Even if you see the directories aligned next to each other in a single line, if you count the number of lines with `wc -l` you will see that the result is number of directories.

Comment: This is the simplest solution to get a vertical list of the directories, without the forward slashes `/`.

Answer (score 88):

For all folders *without* subfolders:

```
find /home/alice/Documents -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

For all folders *with* subfolders:

```
find /home/alice/Documents -type d
```

Comment: To match the question (but include dotfiles), the first should be: `find /home/alice/Documents -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d` otherwise you include `/home/alice/Documents` itself. To include symlinks to directories, prefix with `-L`

Comment: This seems like the sanest solutions, since find is the tool that is actually made for this task. You can exclude the first result - ./ for the current directory - by piping to grep -v '^\./$'

Answer (score 46):

#### Four (more) Reliable Options.

An *unquoted* asterisk `*` will be interpreted as a pattern (glob) by the shell. The shell will use it in pathname expansion. It will then generate a list of filenames that match the pattern.

A simple asterisk will match all filenames in the PWD (present working directory). A more complex pattern as `*/` will match all filenames that end in `/`. Thus, all directories. That is why the command:

## 1.- echo.

```
echo */
echo ./*/              ### Avoid misinterpreting filenames like "-e dir"
```

will be expanded (by the shell) to `echo` all directories in the PWD.

---

To test this: Create a directory (`mkdir`) named like test-dir, and `cd` into it:

```
mkdir test-dir; cd test-dir
```

Create some directories:

```
mkdir {cs,files,masters,draft,static}   # Safe directories.
mkdir {*,-,--,-v\ var,-h,-n,dir\ with\ spaces}  # Some a bit less secure.
touch -- 'file with spaces' '-a' '-l' 'filename'    # And some files:
```

---

The command `echo ./*/` will remain reliable even with odd named files:

```
./--/ ./-/ ./*/ ./cs/ ./dir with spaces/ ./draft/ ./files/ ./-h/
./masters/ ./-n/ ./static/ ./-v var/
```

But the spaces in filenames make reading a bit confusing.

---

If instead of `echo`, we use `ls`. The shell is still what is expanding the list of filenames. The shell is the reason to get a list of directories in the PWD. The `-d` option to `ls` makes it list the present directory entry instead of the contents of each directory (as presented by default).

```
ls -d */
```

However, this command is (somewhat) less reliable. It will fail with the odd named files listed above. It will choke with several names. You need to erase one by one till you find the ones with problems.

## 2.- ls

The GNU `ls` will accept the "end of options" (`--`) key.

```
ls -d ./*/                     ### More reliable BSD ls
ls -d -- */                    ### More reliable GNU ls
```

## 3.-printf

To list each directory in its own line (in one column, similar to ls -1), use:

```
$ printf "%s\n" */        ### Correct even with "-", spaces or newlines.
```

And, even better, we could remove the trailing `/`:

```
$ set -- */; printf "%s\n" "${@%/}"        ### Correct with spaces and newlines.
```

An attempt like

```
$ for i in $(ls -d */); do echo ${i%%/}; done
```

will fail on:

- some names (`ls -d */`) as already shown above.
- will be affected by the value of `IFS`.
- will split names on spaces and tabs (with default `IFS`).
- each newline in the name will start a new echo command.

## 4.- Function

Finally, using the argument list inside a function will not affect the arguments list of the present running shell. Simply

```
$ listdirs(){ set -- */; printf "%s\n" "${@%/}"; }
$ listdirs
```

presents this list:

```
--
-
*
cs
dir with spaces
draft
files
-h
masters
-n
static
-v var
```

These options are safe with several types of odd filenames.

Answer (score 30):

The [`tree`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) command is also pretty useful here. By default it will show all files and directories to a complete depth, with some ASCII characters showing the directory tree.

```
$ tree
.
├── config.dat
├── data
│   ├── data1.bin
│   ├── data2.inf
│   └── sql
|   │   └── data3.sql
├── images
│   ├── background.jpg
│   ├── icon.gif
│   └── logo.jpg
├── program.exe
└── readme.txt
```

But if we wanted to get just the directories, without the ASCII tree, and with the full path from the current directory, you could do:

```
$ tree -dfi
.
./data
./data/sql
./images
```

The arguments being:

```
-d     List directories only.
-f     Prints the full path prefix for each file.
-i     Makes tree not print the indentation lines, useful when used in conjunction with the -f option.
```

And if you then want the absolute path, you could start by specifying the full path to the current directory:

```
$ tree -dfi "$(pwd)"
/home/alice/Documents
/home/alice/Documents/data
/home/alice/Documents/data/sql
/home/alice/Documents/images
```

And to limit the number of subdirectories, you can set the max level of subdirectories with `-L level`, e.g.:

```
$ tree -dfi -L 1 "$(pwd)"
/home/alice/Documents
/home/alice/Documents/data
/home/alice/Documents/images
```

More arguments can be seen with [`man tree`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree).

Answer (score 20):

In case you're wondering why output from 'ls -d */' gives you *two* trailing slashes, like:

```
[prompt]$ ls -d */
app//  cgi-bin//  lib//        pub//
```

it's probably because somewhere your shell or session configuration files alias the *ls* command to a version of *ls* that includes the `-F` flag. That flag appends a character to each output name (that's not a plain file) indicating the kind of thing it is.  So one slash is from matching the pattern '*/', and the other slash is the appended type indicator.

To get rid of this issue, you could of course define a different alias for *ls*. However, to temporarily not invoke the alias, you can prepend the command with backslash:

```
\ls -d */
```

Answer (score 18):

### Actual `ls` solution, including symlinks to directories

Many answers here don't actually use `ls` (or only use it in the trivial sense of `ls -d`, while using wildcards for the actual subdirectory matching. A true `ls` solution is useful, since it allows the use of `ls` options for sorting order, etc.

#### Excluding symlinks

One solution using `ls` has been given, but it does something different from the other solutions in that it *excludes symlinks* to directories:

```
ls -l | grep '^d'
```

(possibly piping through `sed` or `awk` to isolate the file names)

#### Including symlinks

In the (probably more common) case that symlinks to directories should be included, we can use the `-p` option of `ls`, which makes it append a slash character to names of directories (including symlinked ones):

```
ls -1p | grep '/$'
```

or, getting rid of the trailing slashes:

```
ls -1p | grep '/$' | sed 's/\/$//'
```

We can add options to `ls` as needed (if a long listing is used, the `-1` is no longer required).

**Note:** if we *want* trailing slashes, but don't want them highlighted by `grep`, we can hackishly remove the highlighting by making the actual matched portion of the line empty:

```
ls -1p | grep -P '(?=/$)'
```

Answer (score 16):

A plain list of the current directory, it'd be:

```
ls -1d */
```

If you want it sorted and clean:

```
ls -1d */ | cut -c 1- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | sort
```

> **Remember:** capitalized characters have different behavior in the sort

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I am using

```sh
ls -d1 /Directory/Path/*;
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty good solution to display it line by line.

Comment: It won't list directories only.  You must add a trailing slash : `ls -d1 /Directory/Path/*/`

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the comment. To list the directories in my current path I had to do this: `ls -d1 ./*/` or this `ls -d1 */`

Answer (score 14):

I just add this to my `.bashrc` file (you could also just type it on the command line if you only need/want it for one session):

```
alias lsd='ls -ld */'
```

Then *lsd* will produce the desired result.

Comment: Couldn't you just use?    ls -l path | grep dr

Comment: "then lsd will produce the desired result." I laugh

Comment: In my experience, it produces a result.

Comment: I use 'lad' (list all directories), and I also included '.*/' to include hidden directories too. Of course, the innuendo is not lost on me either.

Answer (score 13):

If a hidden directory is not needed to be listed, I offer:

```
ls -l | grep "^d" | awk -F" " '{print $9}'
```

And if hidden directories are needed to be listed, use:

```
ls -Al | grep "^d" | awk -F" " '{print $9}'
```

*Or*

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -F"./" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: If you need to know more about **`awk`**, please look at this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/342850/180452)

Comment: Compared to other answers the first option of "ls .. | grep ...| awk" seems excessive scripting.

Comment: You're assuming no directories have whitespace inside their names.

Comment: ls -l | awk '/^d/ {print $9}'
This is what I cam up with :) and since is already there thumb up!

Comment: `ls -l | awk '/^d/ {print $9}'` works, other solutions do not work when there is no directory

Answer (score 11):

## ls and awk (without grep)

No need to use grep since awk can perform regularexpressino check so it is enough to do this:

```
ls -l | awk '/^d/ {print $9}'
```

where `ls -l` list files with permisions 
`awk` filter output 
`'/^d/'` regularexpresion that search only for lines starting with letter `d` (as directory) looking at first line - permisions 
`{print}` would prints all columns
`{print $9}` will print only **9th column** (name) from `ls -l` **output**

Very simple and clean

Answer (score 8):

Try this one. It works for all Linux distribution.

```
ls -ltr | grep drw
```

Comment: `ls -l | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'`

Answer (score 8):

For listing only *directories*:

```
ls -l | grep ^d
```

For listing only *files*:

```
ls -l | grep -v ^d
```

Or also you can do as:

```
ls -ld */
```

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution the most comfortable, I add to the list:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d
```

The difference is that it has no ./ at the beginning, and the folder names are ready to use.

Answer (score 7):

To show folder lists without `/`:

```
ls -d */|sed 's|[/]||g'
```

Comment: or `ls -d1 */ | tr -d "/"`

Comment: No need to call an external command: `set -- */; printf "%s\n" "${@%/}"`

Comment: I like solution of @wholanda. My a bit shorter solution is (tested & works): ls -d */|sed 's|/||g'

Comment: Also having an lsdir alias is useful: alias lsdirs="ls -d */ | sed 's|/||g'"

Answer (score 4):

`*/` is a filename matching pattern that matches directories in the current directory.

To list directories only, I like this function:

```
# Long list only directories
llod () {
  ls -l --color=always "$@" | grep --color=never '^d'
}
```

Put it in your *.bashrc* file.

Usage examples:

```
llod       # Long listing of all directories in current directory
llod -tr   # Same but in chronological order oldest first
llod -d a* # Limit to directories beginning with letter 'a'
llod -d .* # Limit to hidden directories
```

Note: it will break if you use the `-i` option. Here is a fix for that:

```
# Long list only directories
llod () {
  ls -l --color=always "$@" | egrep --color=never '^d|^[[:digit:]]+ d'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Test whether the item is a directory with `test -d`:

```
for i in $(ls); do test -d $i && echo $i ; done
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does, and how it relates to the question.

Comment: it runs teh command 'ls' then loops through the output test-ing if each is a directory and echo-ing if it is..   works but there are better ways

Comment: @ShoeLace: What are some better ways? Are some of them represented in answers here?

Answer (score 4):

```
file * | grep directory
```

Output (on my machine) --

```
[root@rhel6 ~]# file * | grep directory
mongo-example-master:    directory
nostarch:                directory
scriptzz:                directory
splunk:                  directory
testdir:                 directory
```

The above output can be refined more by using [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
file * | grep directory | cut -d':' -f1
mongo-example-master
nostarch
scriptzz
splunk
testdir

* could be replaced with any path that's permitted
 file - determine file type
 grep - searches for string named directory
 -d - to specify a field delimiter
 -f1 - denotes field 1
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI, if you want to print all the files in multi-line, you can do a `ls -1` which will print each file in a separate line. 
file1
file2
file3

Answer (score 2):

I partially solved it with:

```
cd "/path/to/pricipal/folder"

for i in $(ls -d .*/); do sudo ln -s "$PWD"/${i%%/} /home/inukaze/${i%%/}; done
```

```
    ln: «/home/inukaze/./.»: can't overwrite a directory
    ln: «/home/inukaze/../..»: can't overwrite a directory
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.config»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.disruptive»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/innovations»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/sarl»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.e_old»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.gnome2_private»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.gvfs»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.kde»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.local»: too much symbolics links levels
    ln: accesing to «/home/inukaze/.xVideoServiceThief»: too much symbolics links levels
```

Well, this reduce to me, the major part :)

Answer (score 2):

One-liner to list directories only from "here".

With file count.

```
for i in `ls -d */`; do g=`find ./$i -type f -print| wc -l`; echo "Directory $i contains $g files."; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
ls | perl -nle 'print if -d;'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation using [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) which outputs directory names only on separate lines, yes it's ugly, but hey, it works.

```
tree -d | grep -E '^[├|└]' | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

or with awk

```
tree -d | grep -E '^[├|└]' | awk '{print $2}'
```

This is probably better however and will retain the `/` after directory name.

```
ls -l | awk '/^d/{print $9}'
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have space in your folder name $9 print wont work try below command

```
ls -l yourfolder/alldata/ | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9" " $10}'
```

output

```
ls -l yourfolder/alldata/ | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9" " $10}'
testing_Data 
Folder 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to make it full circle, to retrieve the path of every folder, use a combination of Albert's answer as well as Gordans. That should be pretty useful.

```
for i in $(ls -d /pathto/parent/folder/*/); do echo ${i%%/}; done
```

**Output:**

```
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder1/
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder2/
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder3/
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder4/
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder5/
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder6/
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder7/
/pathto/parent/folder/childfolder8/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use for listing only directory names:

```
ls -1d /some/folder/*/ | awk -F "/" "{print \$(NF-1)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, `*/` has nothing to do with `ls` per se; it is done by the shell/Bash, in a process known as *globbing*.

This is why `echo */` and `ls -d */` output the same elements. (The `-d` flag makes `ls` output the directory names and not contents of the directories.)