# Show only subdirectories in command line Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

As simple as: **How to show all sub-directories from current directory in linux?**

I didn't find any question as direct as this one on the forum.

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directory-using-ls-in-bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably `find` you are searching for:

```
find -type d
```

This will list all subdirectories of the folder - recursively. If you don't want them recursively then pass `maxdepth`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Comment: also ls -l /* being /*/*... the level of sub directories.

Comment: Don't hesitate to add this as an answer

Comment: If I click the CheckMark it is considered as The correct answer right? sorry for being such a noob :/

Comment: :) I meant you can add another answer, answering your own question with that `ls /*/*` . It's ok. While answering his own question isn't welcome too much, it is ok in this situation I think. I would upvote it

Comment: Alright! Well in this case I will leave yours as correct.

Comment: Is there a way to omit the parent?

Comment: `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d` @GiovanniBotta