# Retrieving the sub-directory, which had most recently been modified, in a Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, directory, subdirectory

How can I retrieve the sub-directory, which had most recently been modified, in a directory?
I am using a shell script on a Linux distribution (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the ls options

`-t     sort by modification time, newest first`

And only show directories, use something like this answer suggests [Listing only directories using ls in bash: An examination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directory-using-ls-in-bash)

`ls -d */`

And if you want each directory listed on one line (if your file/dirnames have no newlines or crazy characters) I'd add `-1` So all together, this should list directories in the current directory, with the newest modified times at the top

`ls -1td */`

And only the single newest directory:

`ls -1td */ | head -n 1`

Or if you want to compare to a specific time you can use `find` and it's options like `-cmin -cnewer -ctime -mmin -mtime` and find can handle crazy names like newlines, spaces, etc with null terminated names options like `-print0`

Answer (score 0):

How much the subdirectory is modified is irrelevant.  Do you know the name of the subdirectory?  Get its content like this:

```
files=$(ls subdir-name)
for file in ${files}; do
    echo "I see there is a file named ${file}"
done
```

Comment: For me it isn't irrelevant.