# Get content of a file in Java

Tags: java, nio

I want to get the version of Linux using Java code. In different Linux distributions I have file with diffrent name.

```
/etc/*-release
```

How I can get every file content which ends with `-release`?

Comment: The latest version != current version. Do you like to know the current running linux version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`

```
    File f = new File("/etc/");
    File[] allReleaseFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith("-release");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this the best solution? Can I optimize this code?

Comment: What do you want to optimize here? The code is short, precise and readable. You apply a filter to a list of files, the resulting ``File[]`` contains exactly the files you ask for.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Did you try it out? Was it too slow? Don't optimize too soon

Comment: @PeterPenzov This is just a convenience given by API. If you want to do it yourself, you can list all files within `etc` folder and add only those which ends with `release`, in a `for loop`. I don't think you can further optimize this.

Answer (score 2):

Use Java java.io.File#listFiles and then simply iterate over the array that it returns to open the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperty("os.version")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get files by getting output after executing `ls -d /etc/*-release`.

And then work with them via `Java File`.

**See also:**

- [ls command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directory-using-ls-in-bash)
- [How To Execute Shell Command From Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/)

Comment: I think, it's incorrect to run platform-dependent commands instead of using language abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you should use nio nowadays for this type of action:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/etc");
for (Path file : Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*-release"))
    System.out.println (new String(Files.readAllBytes(file), "UTF-8"));
```