# How can I list only directory names, with no trailing "/"?

Tags: grep, cat, ls

by doing the following command in the folder

```
ls -d */ | cut -f1 -d'/'
```

I get entries like:

```
env1
env2
env3
env4
```

how I can use `cat/grep` or `yq/jq` or any other alternative command(s) instead of the  above command?

Comment: What use are you later making of these entries? Iterating over them in a shell script? Or just printing to stdout?

Comment: What you want to achieve? Just list the directories in the current directory?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy printing to stdout

Comment: @kofemann I'm using this command as a script in my groovy code using in helm file to print the list of environments in the output, using this command it print a list of env sequentially, but I need to print them in parallel

Comment: You mean print them _on the same line_?

Comment: note that that's an innately unsafe thing to do: directory names can have spaces. How can you tell the difference between two different directory names printed on the same line, and one name with a space? (The same argument is why line-separating filenames is a bad idea as well, since newlines are _also_ legal inside names; Doing It Right calls for using the NUL character, which is the _only_ character that can't exist in a name, as terminator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options. You can use the [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) command with the options:

```sh
# d: list only directories
# i: no print of indention line
# L: max display depth of the directory tree
tree -di -L 1 "$(pwd)"
```

Or you can also use the [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) command to get the directories and the command [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk):

```sh
# F: input field separator
# $9: print the ninth column of the output
ls -l | grep "^d" | awk -F" " '{print $9}'
```

Or you can use the [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) command to remove the slash:

```sh
# structure: s|regexp|replacement|flags
# g: apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first
ls -d */ | sed 's|[/]||g'
```

I found this solutions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directories-using-ls-in-bash).

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in */; do
  echo "${dir%/}"
done
```

Comment: can I ask you also briefly explain about your answer?