# Listing only directories using ls in Bash but preserve ls format and without dirname

Tags: bash, directory, ls

There are already many answers for [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directories-using-ls-in-bash). But none of them satisfy my requirements. I want

1. List all directories under a directory without using glob (`*`) syntax, i.e. I want to directly use `lsdir somedir`
2. Output should containing basename of the directories like when you just use `ls`, like:

   ```
   $ lsdir path/to/some/dir
   dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4
   ```

   but not this:

   ```
   $ lsdir path/to/dir
   path/to/dir/dir1 path/to/dir/dir2 path/to/dir/dir3 path/to/dir/dir4
   ```

   To satisfy requirement 1, it seems feasible to define a function, but anyway we are going to use `-d` option, to list the directories themselves of the `ls` command parameters.

   And when using `-d` option, `ls` list directory names with its parent prepended, like above.
3. `ls` format (color, align, sort) should be preserved.

   To satisfy requirement 2, we can use `find` but in this way we lose all the `ls` output format, like coloring (based on customized dircolors theme), alignment (output in aligned columns), sorting (sorting customized with various flags and in a column-first manner), and maybe some other things.

I know it's too greedy to want this many features simultaneously, and indeed I can live without all of them.

It's possible to emulate `ls` output format manually but that's too inconsistent.

I wonder if there is a way to achieve this and still utilize `ls`, i.e. how to achieve requirement 2 using `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @M. Nejat Aydin's excellent answer, I am going to improve a little more to make it a useful command, especially with respect to processing options and multiple directories.

```
list_directories() {
  local opts=()
  local args=()
  for i in $(seq $#); do
    if [[ "${!i}" == -* ]]; then
      opts+=("${!i}")
    else
      args+=("${!i}")
    fi
  done
  (( ${#args[@]} == 0 )) && args=('.')
  local -i args_n_1=${#args[@]}-1
  for i in $(seq 0 $args_n_1); do
    if (( ${#args[@]} > 1 )); then
      (( i > 0 )) && echo
      echo "${args[i]}:"
    fi
    (
      shopt -s nullglob 
      cd "${args[i]}" && 
      dirs=(*/) && 
      (( ${#dirs[@]} > 0 )) && 
      ls -d "${opts[@]}" "${dirs[@]%?}" 
    )
  done
}
alias lsd=list_directories
```

This `lsd` can be used with any number of `ls` options and directories freely mixed.

```
$ lsd -h dir1 dir2 -rt ~
```

Note: Semantic meaning changes when you use globs with `lsd`.

`lsd path/to/dir*` list all directories under each directory starting with "path/to/dir".
To list all directories starting with "path/to/dir", use plain old `ls -d path/to/dir*`.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
cd path/to/dir && dirs=(*/) && ls -d "${dirs[@]%?}"
```

or, perhaps

```
(shopt -s nullglob; cd path/to/dir && dirs=(*/) && ((${#dirs[@]} > 0)) && ls -d "${dirs[@]%?}")
```

The second version runs in a subshell and prints nothing if there is no any subdirectory inside `path/to/dir`.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! I didn't expect it could be a simple `cd` command. Maybe just need to wrap the cd in a subshell to not affect cwd of current shell and do some processing of possible additional options.

Comment: @Masquue yes, you can run it in a subshell by enclosing the whole command by `(` and `)`. Also I've added a second version in case there is no subdirectory inside the main directory.

Comment: Love your second version. And may I ask if I want to improve a little more based on your answer, should I edit your answer or post another answer myself?

Comment: And I wonder why I can't at you in comment, forgive me I'm new, is this because of the space in your username? What's the correct format to use?

Comment: @Masquue The author of the answer is notified whenever a comment is written under the answer, so I think there is no need to at the author, perhaps, unless there are other commentators. I don't know the answer of your second question. You can ask or search for it in the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Which one do you mean by my second question? Is it the one about my edit or answer question?

Comment: @Masquue Yes, it is.