# How to write script displaying all subdirectories in the location

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need help. How to write script displaying all subdirectories in the location. I've got something like that:

```
ls -al | grep ^d
```

but it only works in the home directory

Comment: Duplicate of [List sub-directories with ls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5168071/608639), [Listing only directories using ls in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14352290/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

[find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) may be a better choice here:

```
find . -type d
```

which would list all directories from the current directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: It does not appear the OP wants to descend into all subdirectories.

Comment: Apparently, I can't mind read as well as you do.

Comment: No oculus is necessary. OP said *"all subdirectories in the location"*. You don't go below the current location. That equates to a `maxdepth=1` in your `find` command. I'm not clear on which location, but that's a different matter. In the end, the question is yet another off-topic, no effort dump that should be closed.

Comment: I don't read such conclusivity in the question. But you're entitled to your opinion and there's a *possibility* that what you are saying is what OP really meant/wanted.

Comment: again, the script only works in the location where I created it

Comment: @Roundstic That dot (`.`) says the "current directory". You can instead specify any other directory.