# How to get the sub directories of docker mounts using python

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I'm trying to do automation. For that, I need to check whether the children of the source directory in host system are equal to children directory in the destination directory of the container.

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' devtest 
[{bind  /home/usr/location/docker/myapp/target /app   true rprivate}]
```

From the above code `/home/usr/location/docker/myapp/target` is the source from the host and similarly the `/app` is the destination where the mount is binded.

So as per my requirement I need to find the count of sub directory in both the source and destination. In the case of source is calculated using os.walk. But I have no idea about how to find it from the container using python.

I'm using docker-py module as utility for docker. May I know how can I achieve this using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use docker exec on the docker host machine and then use the Linux ls command along with wc to find the directory count.

You can use either the os or subprocess python modules to run the command.
(subprocess is the pythons recommended option).

```
import os

os.system("docker exec <container-id/name> ls /app |wc -l")
```

You can use -d option in the command, if you want to run it as a daemon.

Comment: What if I need only the subdirectories?

Comment: This should help to list the sub directories. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168071/list-sub-directories-with-ls

Comment: os.system not working but typing the same thing into the command prompt works

Comment: You should be able to get the results into a variable (result = os.system (<command>) ) and use that, could you provide any error messages, which is generated..?

Comment: Can we use subprocess to acheive these

Comment: Yes, this should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python

Comment: I tried print(subprocess.run(["docker" ,"exec", "-d", "devtest", "ls", "/app/.", "|", "wc", "-l"])) but it output as CompletedProcess(args=['docker', 'exec', '-d', 'devtest', 'ls', '/app/.', '|', 'wc', '-l'], returncode=0)

Comment: remove the -d and try

Comment: args = split("docker exec  devtest ls /app/. | wc -l")
        mnt_out = subprocess.run(args=args)
it output as below `/app/.:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 1000 1000 4096 May  7 14:16 Children1
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 May  7 09:38 Children2
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 May  7 14:56 Children3
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  650 May  7 13:24 question
ls: cannot access '|': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'wc': No such file or directory
None
` But same thing work on terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213343/discussion-between-dvs-and-edward-arrow).

Answer (score 0):

You can run commands with `subprocess` and `shlex`

```py
import subprocess
from shlex import split

args = split("docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' devtest")
mnt_out = subprocess.run(args=args, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(mnt_out.stdout)
```

This will print as if it was on terminal. From there you can build the logic you wish to archive with pure python using `pathlib` library for example.